# Pyinstaller fatal error: returned -1

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4, pyinstaller

What I want to do is obtain an executable file (onefile or onefolder is not important) from my script (written in Python 3.5 with PyQt4).
When I run the pyinstaller command (for example *pyinstaller -w MyApp.py*) the folder is created but when I double click on the MyApp.exe a small window appears with Fatal error: MyApp returned -1.
I tried to downgrade pyinstaller and/or setuptools version but without solve the problem.
I've simplified my script so that it can be used by anyone (the original one asks for measures from 2 multimeters): the code is the following.

```
# Imports
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from datetime import datetime
import threading
from math import floor
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, AutoDateLocator
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import random
import numpy as np
import time

date_format = "%d/%m/%Y %H.%M.%S"


def threaded(fn):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        threading.Thread(target=fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs).start()

    return wrapper


class MyCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    """Matplotlib Figure widget"""

    def __init__(self):
        # first image setup
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax2 = self.ax1.twinx()

        # initialization of the canvas
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)

        # set X axis for date and time
        self.fig.autofmt_xdate()
        self.ax1.xaxis_date()
        formatter = DateFormatter('%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
        self.ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
        locator = AutoDateLocator()
        self.ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)

        # resize the plot
        box = self.ax1.get_position()
        self.ax1.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])
        self.ax2.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])

        # set axes labels
        self.ax1.set_ylabel('Current [A]', size=12, color='b')
        self.ax2.set_ylabel('Voltage [V]', size=12, color='r')
        self.ax1.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=10)
        self.ax2.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=10)

        # generates first "empty" plots
        self.x_axis_values, self.current_curve, self.voltage_curve = [], [], []

        # generates first element in timeline
        now = datetime.now()
        self.x_axis_values.append(now)
        self.current_curve.append(0)
        self.voltage_curve.append(0)

        self.l_current_curve, = self.ax1.plot(self.x_axis_values, self.current_curve, '-b', label='I_A1')
        self.l_voltage_curve, = self.ax2.plot(self.x_axis_values, self.voltage_curve, '-r', label='V_A2-A3')

        # add legend to plot
        h1, l1 = self.ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
        h2, l2 = self.ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
        self.ax1.legend(h1 + h2, l1 + l2, loc='upper left', prop={'size': 10}, bbox_to_anchor=(1.15, 1))

        # force a redraw of the Figure
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

        # initialize X and Y axes values
        self.x, self.y1, self.y2 = None, None, None

        # this variable becomes True when new elements are ready to be plotted
        self.ready = False

        # call the update method (to speed-up visualization)
        self.timerEvent(None)

        # start timer, trigger event every 200 millisecs (=0.2sec)
        self.timer = self.startTimer(200)

    @threaded
    def timerEvent(self, evt):
        """
        Custom timerEvent code, called at timer event receive
        :param evt:
        :return:
        """

        # get result data
        if self.ready is True:
            x_datetime = self.x
            result = [self.y1, self.y2]

            # append new data to the datasets
            self.x_axis_values.append(x_datetime)
            self.current_curve.append(result[0])
            self.voltage_curve.append(result[1])

            # update lines data using the lists with new data
            self.l_current_curve.set_xdata(self.x_axis_values)
            self.l_current_curve.set_ydata(self.current_curve)
            self.l_voltage_curve.set_xdata(self.x_axis_values)
            self.l_voltage_curve.set_ydata(self.voltage_curve)

            datemin = min(self.x_axis_values)
            datemax = max(self.x_axis_values)
            self.ax1.set_xlim(datemin, datemax)
            self.ax2.set_xlim(datemin, datemax)
            self.ax1.set_xticks(np.linspace(self.ax1.get_xbound()[0], self.ax1.get_xbound()[1], 5))
            y1min = min(self.current_curve)
            y1max = max(self.current_curve)
            self.ax1.set_ylim(floor(y1min) - 1, floor(y1max) + 2)
            y2min = min(self.voltage_curve)
            y2max = max(self.voltage_curve)
            self.ax2.set_ylim(floor(y2min) - 1, floor(y2max) + 2)
            self.ax1.set_yticks(np.linspace(self.ax1.get_ybound()[0], self.ax1.get_ybound()[1], 10))
            self.ax2.set_yticks(np.linspace(self.ax2.get_ybound()[0], self.ax2.get_ybound()[1], 10))

            # force a redraw of the Figure
            self.fig.canvas.draw()

            self.ready = False


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    dict_items = {}
    first_time = True
    start_time = time.strftime(date_format, time.localtime(time.time()))
    busy = False
    path = 'C:\sample.csv'

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        # Initialize the main window
        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.setFixedSize(800, 480)  # define the window size
        self.setLayoutDirection(Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.setStyleSheet("")
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        # Initialize the central widget
        self.centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        # Initialize the tab widget
        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget(self.centralWidget)
        # Initialize the configure tab
        self.Configure = QWidget()
        self.startButton = QPushButton(self.Configure)
        self.stopButton = QPushButton(self.Configure)
        # Initialize the table tab
        self.Table = QWidget()
        self.tableView = QTableView(self.Table)
        self.model = QStandardItemModel(self)
        # Initialize the graph tab
        self.Graph = QWidget()
        style.use('bmh')
        self.canvas = MyCanvas()
        self.mpl_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        self.vbl = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.vbl.addWidget(self.mpl_toolbar)
        self.Graph.setLayout(self.vbl)
        # Launch functions to define the layouts and actions
        self.central_widget()
        self.tab_widget()
        self.configure_tab()
        self.add_configure()
        self.table_tab()
        self.add_table()
        self.graph_tab()
        self.add_graph()
        self.configure_buttons()
        self.edit_actions()

    def central_widget(self):
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

    def tab_widget(self):
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 700, 420))
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(8)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.tabWidget.setFont(font)
        self.tabWidget.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QTabWidget.North)
        self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.tabWidget.setIconSize(QSize(32, 32))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def configure_tab(self):
        self.Configure.setObjectName("Configure")

    def add_configure(self):
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.Configure, "")
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.Configure), "Configure")

    def table_tab(self):
        self.Table.setObjectName("Table")
        self.tableView.setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 670, 370))
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        font = QFont("Tahoma", 7)
        self.tableView.setFont(font)
        self.tableView.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(18)

    def add_table(self):
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.Table, "")
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.Table), "Table")

    def graph_tab(self):
        self.Graph.setObjectName("Graph")

    def add_graph(self):
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.Graph, "")
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.Graph), "Graph")

    def configure_buttons(self):
        self.startButton.setGeometry(QRect(20, 70, 131, 23))
        self.startButton.setStyleSheet("")
        self.startButton.setText("START")
        self.stopButton.setGeometry(QRect(220, 70, 131, 23))
        self.stopButton.setStyleSheet("")
        self.stopButton.setText("STOP")

    def edit_actions(self):
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.start_action)
        self.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.stop_action)

    def start_action(self):
        self.busy = True
        if self.first_time:
            self.write_header()
            self.first_time = False
            self.start_time = time.strftime(date_format, time.localtime(time.time()))
        self.logging()

    def stop_action(self):
        self.busy = False
        self.canvas.killTimer(self.canvas.timer)

    def write_header(self):
        header = ['Date [D/M/Y H.M.S]', 'Time [h.m.s]', 'M1:...', 'M2:...']
        self.model.clear()
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(header)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        header_string = ','.join(header)
        f = open(self.path, 'w')
        f.write(header_string + '\n')
        f.close()

    def write_row(self, row):
        row_list = list(row.split(','))
        elements = [QStandardItem(item) for item in row_list]
        self.model.appendRow(elements)

    @threaded
    def logging(self):
        while self.busy is True:
            n = datetime.now()
            now = time.localtime(time.time())
            time_list = self.get_time(now)
            self.measuring(time_list, n)
            time.sleep(1)

    @threaded
    def measuring(self, time_list, now):
        r1 = 10 * random.random() ** 2
        r2 = random.random() * random.randint(1, 10) ** 2
        meas_row = str(r1) + "," + str(r2)
        row = time_list[0] + "," + time_list[1] + "," + meas_row + '\n'
        f = open(self.path, 'a')
        f.write(row)
        f.close()
        self.write_row(row)
        self.canvas.x = now
        self.canvas.y1 = r1
        self.canvas.y2 = r2
        self.canvas.ready = True

    def get_time(self, n):
        t = time.strftime(date_format, n)
        t2 = datetime.strptime(t, date_format)
        t1 = datetime.strptime(self.start_time, date_format)
        d0 = t2 - t1
        days = d0.days
        seconds = d0.seconds
        m, s = divmod(seconds, 60)
        h, m = divmod(m, 60)
        h += 24 * days
        d = str(h) + '.' + str(m) + '.' + str(s)
        td = [t, d]
        return td


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('Meter')
    test = MainWindow()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And here is what is generated by pyinstaller command.

```
C:\Users\Leo Raimondo\Documents\Python Scripts\test04>pyinstaller -w MyApp.py
126 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.1.1
127 INFO: Python: 3.5.1
127 INFO: Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
128 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Leo Raimondo\Documents\Python Scripts\test04\MyApp.spec

132 INFO: UPX is not available.
134 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Leo Raimondo\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\test04',
 'C:\\Users\\Leo Raimondo\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\test04']
135 INFO: checking Analysis
135 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
135 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
141 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
147 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5024 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
5566 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Leo Raimondo\Documents\Python Scripts\test04\MyApp
.py
5898 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
8319 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
8320 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyI
nstaller\\fake-modules'
13056 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
15623 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   six.moves
32523 INFO: Looking for import hooks ...
32529 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PyQt4.py
32531 INFO: Processing hook   hook-setuptools.py
32533 INFO: Processing hook   hook-sqlite3.py
32538 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pygments.py
33833 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PyQt4.QtGui.py
34470 INFO: Processing hook   hook-cryptography.py
34477 INFO: Processing hook   hook-matplotlib.backends.py
35420 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK": ignored
    Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.
36129 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTKAgg": ignored
    Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.
36595 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTKCairo": ignored
    No module named 'gtk'
37275 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "MacOSX": ignored
    cannot import name '_macosx'
38008 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Agg": added
38740 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Agg": added
39507 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkAgg": added
40169 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WX": ignored
    Matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxPython >=2.8.12
40881 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXAgg": ignored
    Matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxPython >=2.8.12
41347 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Cairo": ignored
    Gtk3 backend requires pygobject to be installed.
42013 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Agg": ignored
    Gtk3 backend requires pygobject to be installed.
42518 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WebAgg": ignored
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_webagg.py", l
ine 32, in <module>
    import tornado.web
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 82, in <module>
    from tornado.concurrent import Future
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 37, in <modu
le>
    from concurrent import futures
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\concurrent\futures\__init__.py", line 8,
in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 355
    raise type(self._exception), self._exception, self._traceback
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
43022 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "nbAgg": ignored
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_nbagg.py", li
ne 14, in <module>
    import tornado.ioloop
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 46, in <module>
    from tornado.concurrent import TracebackFuture, is_future
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 37, in <modu
le>
    from concurrent import futures
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\concurrent\futures\__init__.py", line 8,
in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 355
    raise type(self._exception), self._exception, self._traceback
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
43700 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "agg": added
44164 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "cairo": ignored
    Cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed.
44629 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "emf": ignored
    No module named 'matplotlib.backends.backend_emf'
45086 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "gdk": ignored
    No module named 'gobject'
45784 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pdf": added
47049 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pgf": added
47719 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "ps": added
48430 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "svg": added
49108 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "template": added
49299 INFO: Processing hook   hook-requests.py
49305 INFO: Processing hook   hook-distutils.py
49307 INFO: Processing hook   hook-xml.dom.domreg.py
49308 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pydoc.py
49309 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pycparser.py
49426 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PyQt4.QtCore.py
49554 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pythoncom.py
50051 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pytz.py
50175 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PIL.py
50181 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
50188 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QtGui.QImage
50188 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QtCore
50189 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QtCore.QBuffer
50189 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QtGui.qRgba
50189 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QtGui.QPixmap
50190 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QtGui
50190 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QtCore.QIODevice
50191 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
50197 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
50198 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
50204 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt5
50204 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt5.QPixmap
50205 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt5.qRgba
50205 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt5.QImage
50206 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
50212 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PySide.QPixmap
50212 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PySide.qRgba
50213 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PySide.QImage
50214 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PySide
50214 INFO: Processing hook   hook-zmq.py
50701 INFO: Excluding import 'zmq.libzmq'
50707 WARNING:   From zmq removing import zmq.libzmq
50710 INFO: Processing hook   hook-xml.py
50711 INFO: Processing hook   hook-jsonschema.py
50715 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pkg_resources.py
51073 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PyQt4.QtSvg.py
51074 INFO: Processing hook   hook-matplotlib.py
51572 INFO: Processing hook   hook-_tkinter.py
51842 INFO: checking Tree
51842 INFO: Building Tree because out00-Tree.toc is non existent
51843 INFO: Building Tree out00-Tree.toc
51953 INFO: checking Tree
51954 INFO: Building Tree because out01-Tree.toc is non existent
51954 INFO: Building Tree out01-Tree.toc
51971 INFO: Processing hook   hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py
51973 INFO: Processing hook   hook-win32com.py
52100 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PIL.Image.py
52344 INFO: Processing hook   hook-jinja2.py
52360 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pywintypes.py
52841 INFO: Processing hook   hook-encodings.py
52853 INFO: Processing hook   hook-IPython.py
90688 INFO: Processing hook   hook-sysconfig.py
90690 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py
90700 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
90710 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
90711 INFO: Processing hook   hook-patsy.py
90712 INFO: Processing hook   hook-docutils.py
91365 INFO: Processing hook   hook-scipy.io.matlab.py
91367 INFO: Processing hook   hook-lxml.etree.py
91375 INFO: Processing hook   hook-sphinx.py
95591 INFO: Processing hook   hook-babel.py
95749 INFO: Processing hook   hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py
95751 INFO: Processing hook   hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py
95755 INFO: Processing hook   hook-boto.py
95787 INFO: Processing hook   hook-sqlalchemy.py
96115 WARNING: Hidden import 'MySQLdb' not found (probably old hook)
96116 INFO: Processing hook   hook-idlelib.py
96127 INFO: Processing hook   hook-tables.py
96129 INFO: Processing hook   hook-scipy.linalg.py
96411 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
96502 WARNING: library dllpaths required via ctypes not found
96516 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
96578 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
96581 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
96583 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
96585 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_qt4plugins.py'
96588 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_mplconfig.py'
96590 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_mpldata.py'
96723 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
98251 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp35-win_amd64.pyd dependency of c:\anacond
a3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\message.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
98443 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp35-win_amd64.pyd dependency of c:\anacond
a3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\error.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
98633 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp35-win_amd64.pyd dependency of c:\anacond
a3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\socket.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
98823 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp35-win_amd64.pyd dependency of c:\anacond
a3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\_poll.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
99016 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp35-win_amd64.pyd dependency of c:\anacond
a3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\utils.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
99209 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp35-win_amd64.pyd dependency of c:\anacond
a3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\context.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
99413 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp35-win_amd64.pyd dependency of c:\anacond
a3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\_device.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
99604 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.cp35-win_amd64.pyd dependency of c:\anacond
a3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\_version.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
101598 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerc
ases: PIL._imaging
101598 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerc
ases: PIL._imagingft
101599 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerc
ases: PyQt4.QtSvg
101600 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerc
ases: Cython.Compiler.Scanning
101600 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerc
ases: Cython.Compiler.Parsing
101601 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerc
ases: Cython.Compiler.Code
101601 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerc
ases: Cython.Compiler.Visitor
101601 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerc
ases: Cython.Compiler.FlowControl
101602 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerc
ases: scipy.optimize.moduleTNC
101603 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerc
ases: PyQt4.QtCore
101603 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerc
ases: PyQt4.QtGui
101604 INFO: Looking for eggs
101604 INFO: Using Python library c:\anaconda3\python35.dll
101604 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
101730 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\Leo Raimondo\Documents\Python Scripts\
test04\build\MyApp\warnMyApp.txt
102089 INFO: checking PYZ
102090 INFO: Building PYZ because out00-PYZ.toc is non existent
102090 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Leo Raimondo\Documents\Python S
cripts\test04\build\MyApp\out00-PYZ.pyz
105908 INFO: checking PKG
105909 INFO: Building PKG because out00-PKG.toc is non existent
105909 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
105961 INFO: Bootloader c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Wi
ndows-64bit\runw.exe
105961 INFO: checking EXE
105962 INFO: Building EXE because out00-EXE.toc is non existent
105962 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
105980 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\Leo Raimondo\Documents\Python Scr
ipts\test04\build\MyApp\MyApp.exe
106018 INFO: checking COLLECT
106019 INFO: Building COLLECT because out00-COLLECT.toc is non existent
106019 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc
```